# Obtener toda la informacion de una imagen en PHP

Tags: php, imagen

Buen día. Espero que me puedan ayudar, trabajo con una página en donde muestro toda la información de las imágenes que se suben, hasta el momento todo bien el único inconveniente es que no logro obtener el dato (Title) que se muestra en la imagen. Uso el comando exif_read_data para obtener toda la información pero no muestra el dato que busco. Agradezco su ayuda y sus consejos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué dato buscas?

Comment: Title, es el que esta en azul en la imagen

Comment: No todas las imágenes tienen `metadatos`, pero puedes intentar con [`exif_read_data()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.exif-read-data.php)

Comment: exif_read_data() es lo que uso para obtener la mayor parte de información pero no me da el dato que necesito.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la función `var_dump` de PHP para examinar la estructura de los datos que te regresa la función `exif_read_data`.

Deberás asegurarte de que el título no está anidado en algún lugar de los datos que te regresa dicha función.

Puedes probar cosas como:

```php
$datosExif = exif_read_data($rutaArchivo);
var_dump($datosExif);
var_dump($datosExif['IFD0']);
var_dump($datosExif['WINXP']);
```

Comment: Lo intente pero solo muestra el tipo de dato de cada elemento. No muestra el dato que deseo